# Ionic 6 vue project need to make it SSR

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, server-side-rendering

I have an ionic 6 project written with vue js.
I need to add SSR functionality and deploy it to the hosting.

The PWA works fine, but I need to convert it to SSR.
I'm using vuex as a store state.

Here is the current package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "description": "My Project",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
        "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@capacitor/app": "1.0.3",
        "@capacitor/core": "3.2.4",
        "@capacitor/device": "^1.0.3",
        "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.0",
        "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.0",
        "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
        "@ionic/core": "^6.0.7",
        "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.7",
        "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.7",
        "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^4.0.5",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.6",
        "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.2.47",
        "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.28",
        "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.23",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "firebase": "^9.8.1",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-gtag": "^2.0.1",
        "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.11",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
        "vue3-google-map": "^0.8.2",
        "vue3-tel-input": "^1.0.4",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.4",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5",
        "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
    }
}
```

Here is the main.ts file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { store, key } from "./store";
import router from "./router";
import i18n from "@/i18n";
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";
import "./registerServiceWorker";

import { IonicVue } from "@ionic/vue";

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/vue/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/vue/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/structure.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/vue/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/display.css";

/* Bootstrap */
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

/* Theme variables */
import "./theme/variables.css";
import "./theme/style-ar.css";
import "./theme/main.css";
import "./theme/responsive.css";
import "./theme/header.css";
import "./theme/account.css";
import "./theme/form.css";
import "./theme/uicons-regular-straight.css";

const app = createApp(App)
    .use(IonicVue)
    .use(store, key)
    .use(i18n)
    .use(router)
    .use(
        VueGtag,
        {
            appName: "PWA",
            bootstrap: false,
        },
        router
    );

router.isReady().then(() => {
    app.mount("#app");
});
```

I've tried some tutorials but it failed to work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to convert an ionic Vue app, into an SSR page.

One alternative might be to build an SSR page with nuxt and then add capacitor to make it into a mobile app. This way, of course, you can't use the Ionic components.

Another alternative is to use the Quasar Framework, which offers SSR and SPA out of the box. https://quasar.dev/introduction-to-quasar#what-is-quasar

Comment: Right. After hours of tries and coding here and there, I'm rebuilding the project with Nuxt 3